# Find items by their properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a map of items to their attributes:

```
    OPTIONS = {
      paper: %w[A4_paper countable universal],
      pencil: %w[trackable universal trackable],
      chalk: %w[stationery countable trackable A4_paper],
    }.freeze
```

I need to return the items that have a particular attribute.  For example, `fetch_type_values('countable')` should return `["paper", "chalk"]`.

Here's my working implementation:

```
def fetch_type_values(option)
 OPTIONS.map { |key, value| key if value.include?(option.to_s) }.compact.map(&:to_s)
end
```

I feel that this is a bit difficult to read; How can I refactor/simplify it to make it more readable?

Comment: I changed the question so that it describes the purpose, to the best of my understanding. Please check that I haven't misunderstood, and correct it if I have.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks good to me. My only complaint is you're calling `.to_s()` more times than necessary -- but that's a concise readability versus CPU cycles tradeoff. For "small" `option` arguments, the code as written is better than assigning a temp var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use select since that is what you are really doing

```
def fetch_type_values(option)
 OPTIONS.select { |_key, value| value.include?(option.to_s) }.map(&:to_s)
end
```

I also wouldn't stringify the result. I would keep the options as symbols since that is your internal representation. I would even make the attributes symbols. i.e.

```
    OPTIONS = {
      paper: %i[A4_paper countable universal],
      pencil: %i[trackable universal trackable],
      chalk: %i[stationery countable trackable A4_paper],
    }.freeze
```